# publish live Stream using wowza and webRtc

Tags: websocket, webrtc, wowza

I am publishing stream from webrtc to wowza but my socket connection aborts abruptly and i get in console wsConnection.onclose[object CloseEvent] 
and in error during wsConnection.onclose i got error code : 1006

Comment: The `onclose` event `1006` is simply "Abnormal".  What does the event from your `onerror` contain?  Also check the wowza logs for anything that may have gone wrong here: `/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/logs`